Format-Volume in PowerShell script output at the end of the whole script
The following is the code of test.ps1:
Write-Host "Message before Format-Volume"
Format-Volume -DriveLetter I -FileSystem exFAT -AllocationUnitSize 131072
Write-Host "Message after Format-Volume"

And the output:
PS C:\Users\user> E:\Scripts\test.ps1
Message before Format-Volume

Message after Format-Volume
DriveLetter FriendlyName FileSystemType DriveType HealthStatus OperationalStatus SizeRemaining      Size
----------- ------------ -------------- --------- ------------ ----------------- -------------      ----
I                        exFAT          Removable Healthy      OK                    115.44 GB 115.45 GB

As you can see the order of output is not the same as the code. Why? How to make sure the order is correct?
What I've tried:

Use Start-Job/Receive-Job to quote Format-Volume

What was I expecting?

The result of Format-Volume should be displayed at the middle.


I found that pipe the result of Format-Volume to Out-Host got what I want, but why? Out-Host should be the default, right?

No, Out-Host is not the default. PowerShell cmdlets normally use the Success stream which buffers output until the end of the script. Using Format-Volume | Out-Host forces immediate display by moving the output to the Host stream, which is why you see the results in the order you want instead of at the end.

You can use Out-Host to force immediate output.
Write-Host "Message before Format-Volume"
Format-Volume -DriveLetter I -FileSystem exFAT -AllocationUnitSize 131072 | Out-Host
Write-Host "Message after Format-Volume"

